# something wrong with xml

Tags: xml, asp-classic

I dont understand why it does not display blog entries as

```
 <rss version="2.0">
 <channel>
 <title></title>

 <item>
 <title>Title to story 1</title>
 <description>Fusce ornare. Pellentesque convallis, lorem vel imperdiet
 </description>
 </item>
 −
 </channel>
 </rss>
```

Going mad here, any advise appreciated!!

http://www.pangeaadvisors.org/sep123/blog.cs.asp?Process=ViewBlog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server is claiming that the data at that URL is text/html instead of application/rss+xml.

Answer (score 1):

Review these validator results:

http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pangeaadvisors.org%2Fsep123%2Fblog.cs.asp%3FProcess%3DViewBlog

Comment: This is giving me stomachaches. I used this format million times. Now validator is giving me, Undefined root element: rows error.